# Visual Flow fail: required field missing (yet I have required field)

Tags: error, visual-workflow, flow, trailhead

I'm working on the Trailhead Visual Workflow unit, and my flow keeps failing and I'm not sure why. The error message I get says, "caused by element : FlowRecordCreate.New_Opportunity
caused by: UPSERT --- UPSERT FAILED --- ERRORS : (REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING) Required fields are missing: [StageName] --- for SFDC record with ID : null," but clearly you can see in the photo I have the Stage Name field. What am I missing? Thanks!!! Now adding my input screen as well. [[image: inputScreenFail]] Now adding prospecting choice screen. [image: prospectingchoicefail][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amBZv.png)

[image: trailheadFail]

Comment: The Field you're using on the left is more of a "label". The `{!Opportunity_Stage}` is the input field in your page. Do you really have all the required fields that Salesforce expects when inserting a record using the proper syntax? `{!OneMonthFromToday}` is not `Opportunity.CloseDate`.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev, that's super helpful and I understand what you're saying! So if I want to have a close date that is one month from today, would I set that up on the first screen, the input screen?

Comment: So the weird thing is when I go to associate 'opportunity stage' from the screen input field, because I've put 'Prospecting' as the default field, it's showing up under 'screen choice fields', not screen input fields. Could that be the issue? Again, still not sure how to set default values as the trailhead module is asking, while still meeting the required fields need.

Comment: Hi Missy! I think your problem might be back at the initial Screen where you are collecting the information. Can you put a screen shot for that up also?

Comment: Sorry one more screen, can you also add the Prospecting choice setup screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored value needs to be assigned to the Prospecting choice. Think of the Label/Unique Name as a variable name and "Prospecting" as the value inside of the variable. I've seen conventions where people put a c_ in front of the variable name to help differentiate what type of variable it is.
So on the entry screen, it will check what is inside the variable and assign it to the stage as a default, currently it is assigning null since stored value is empty.
[image: Default Stage Choice variable]